# Change Gridview row value based on current date in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, gridview, rowdatabound

I am not able to solve this. I want to check if the received date (DateOfRecd) is passed from current date, then it should be red.

But I cant. Please help me. My code is:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ItemTypeName" HeaderText="ItemTypeName" SortExpression="ItemTypeName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="BrandName" HeaderText="BrandName" SortExpression="BrandName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ModelName" HeaderText="ModelName" SortExpression="ModelName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="ItemSerial" HeaderText="ItemSerial" SortExpression="ItemSerial" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfRecd" HeaderText="DateOfRecd" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yy}" SortExpression="DateOfRecd" />
```

My C# Code is:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string v_ExpiryDate = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DateOfRecd");
        string Test = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToDateTime(v_ExpiryDate)).ToString();
        if (Test == "0")
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt the value of `Test` will ever be `0`. `DateTime.Compare` gives 3 possible values, -1, 0 and 1. It will be negative if T1 is smaller than T2 and 1 when T1 is bigger than T2.
The value will only be 0 when the two dates are the same and that is highly unlikely since `DateTime.Now` give you the time to the second. So if `DateOfRecd` is not accurate to the second the moment you open the page the GridView row will never be red.

I think you only want the Date part, not the hours and seconds. So use `DateTime.Now.Date'

```
string Test = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now.Date, Convert.ToDateTime(v_ExpiryDate)).ToString();
```

Or just compare the dates directly.

```
if (DateTime.Now.Date > ExpiryDate)
{
    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```